# How can an IC generate -24 V, 1 A peak from a 12 V power supply?

Tags: switching-regulator

Can anyone explain if a switching voltage regulator IC could be capable of outputting -24 V, 1 A peak from my +12 V power supply?

I tried to use the [LT8334](https://www.analog.com/en/products/lt8334.html#product-overview), but no luck; the output voltage drops with just 1 mA load current.

Comment: Site rule: *Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete.*

Comment: Without digging too deeply, the LT8334 seems like a suitable part (although 1A might be near its limits, as is -24V out). Reworking the question into 'why isn't my inverting converter working' might work better. Provide diagrams and a list of your parts.

Comment: https://www.electronicspecifier.com/products/power/creating-a-negative-output-voltage-using-a-buck-converter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help : [link](http://schmidt-walter-schaltnetzteile.de/smps_e/ivw_smps_e.html).

Made with [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm) ... FREE.

Here is a sample of an SMPS supply boost inverter from 12V to ~ -24V / 1A.
Not checked all voltages, currents, and powers for all components.
Efficiency seems to be about 65% but it could be better.
Note that the pulse generator should be a PWM wave (starting softly with low Duty cycle).

Starting "blocks" ...
[image]

Steady-state waves ...
[image]